# Auto increment mule domain project and all child projects

Tags: maven, mule, mule4

We are having a domain project and there are 8 other projects which have a dependency on it.

Every time, when we do some changes to the domain project we have to increment the snapshot version and also increment all child projects manually which is a huge pain.

Is there a better way to auto-increment the version in the domain project during every update and also to update all other child projects referring to it automatically?

`<groupId>com.xyz</groupId> <version>1.1.0</version>`
the same version has to be updated in all other child projects referring to it.

Comment: What version of Mule are you using?

Comment: Why not using Maven release plugin, or versions plugin etc? instead of manually changing the versions?

Comment: @aled we are using mule 4.4

Answer (score 0):

Since Mule 4.2.2 domains can be referenced using semantic versioning, so you don't need to update the applications that reference that domain. You can deploy the new version of the domain with an increased version, and Mule applications will accept it as compatible if it has a higher version.

From the documentation topic [Associate Applications with a Domain](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/shared-resources#assoc_apps_domain):

> - The version honors semantic versioning.
>
> For example, if you set the version to 1.0.1, a domain with version 1.0.2 > and later works, but a domain with version 1.0.0 does not.